# Introductory text on curve shortening flow

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, mean-curvature-flows

I have been using [this](http://smp.uq.edu.au/sites/smp.uq.edu.au/files/GeometricFlowsBook_Ch2.pdf) pdf as a primary source for the introductory part of a project on CSF I'm currently writing. Since it says 'Chapter 2' above the title, it implies this work is part of some larger text (or possibly even book), but I have not been able to find any such material beyond this chapter. I was wondering if anyone knew where this text was from/who authored it? I would like to cite it beyond just giving the url.

Alternatively I would appreciate being pointed in the direction of alternative sources pitched at a similar level. So far all I have found are a couple of sets of lecture notes, and the material that can be found at the beginning of the classic research papers of Gage, Hamilton, Grayson etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this is part of a book on geometric flows in preparation by Ben Andrews and possibly some co-authors... can't remember any details and don't know whether it's still in preparation, but I'm pretty sure it's not published. The pdf is from his provided reading for [this winter school](https://www.smp.uq.edu.au/content/preliminary-readings) a few years ago.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis, do you have the complete PDF that you linked on your comment? The link isn't work more.

Comment: @jl2 It seems that one cannot find the book in your link anymore.

Comment: @ArcticChar I imagine this is because the book from which it was taken ('Extrinsic Geometric Flows' by Andrews, Chow and Guenther) has now been published.